# Los datos ingresados en un ArrayList desde una clase no se ejecutan en otra

Tags: java, arraylist

Soy nuevo en Java, y estoy tratando de desarrollar un pequeño programa que gestione turnos de una farmacia. Consiste en una terminal para clientes (donde sacan el turno) que añade a un ArrayList en la clase 'Cola' cada turno que se va sacando.

Clase Cola:

```
    public class Cola {
    private static ArrayList<String> cola = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void anadirElem(String elem) {
        cola.add(elem);
    }

    public static void anadirElemPrior(String elem) {
        cola.add(0, elem);
    }

    public static void sacarElem() {
        cola.remove(0);
    }

    public static String getElem(int posic) {
        String ultElem = cola.get(posic);
        return ultElem;
    }

    public static int getTam() {
        return cola.size();
    }

}
```

Clase TerminalCliente:

```
    public class TerminalCliente {
    private static int ultOS = 1;
    public static int ultPart = 1;
    private static int ultPrior = 1;


    public static void generarOS() {
        String turno = "OS-";
        turno = turno + ultOS;
        ultOS++;

        Cola.anadirElem(turno);
        System.out.println("Su turno es el " + turno);
    }

    public static void generarPart() {
        String elem = "PA-" + ultPart;
        ultPart++;

      Cola.anadirElem(elem);
        System.out.println("Su turno es el " + elem);
    }

    public static void generarPrior() {
        String elem = "PR-" + ultPrior;
        ultPrior++;

        Cola.anadirElemPrior(elem);
        System.out.println("Su turno es el " + elem);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true) {

            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Le damos la bienvenida a Farmacias Java.");
            System.out.println("Para Obras Sociales escriba OS");
            System.out.println("Para atención a Particulares escriba PA");
            System.out.println("Para atención prioritaria (adultos mayores, embarazadas, discapacitados) escriba PR");

            String tipo = s.next();

            if (tipo.equals("OS")) {
                generarOS();
            }
            if (tipo.equals("PA")) {
                generarPart();
            }
            if (tipo.equals("PR")) {
                generarPrior();
            }
            if (tipo.equals("L")) {
                for(int i = 0; i < Cola.getTam(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(Cola.getElem(i));
                }
            }
            if(tipo.equals("TAM")){
                System.out.println(Cola.getTam());
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, se añaden al ArrayList. Pero, desde la terminal del empleado, que es la siguiente:

```
    public class TerminalEmpleado {
    private static int nroPuesto = 1;
    private static boolean recibOS = true;
    private static String proxTurno;

    public static void getProxTurno() {
        if(recibOS == true){
            proxTurno = Cola.getElem(0);
        }
        else {
            int posProxTurno = -1;

            for(int i = Cola.getTam(); i < 0; i--){
                String turno = Cola.getElem(i);

                if(turno.substring(0, 2) == "PA"){
                    posProxTurno = i;
                }
            }

            proxTurno = Cola.getElem(posProxTurno);
        }
    }

    public static void llamar() {
        PantallaProxTurno.mostrar(proxTurno, nroPuesto);
        Cola.sacarElem();
        getProxTurno();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Puesto de empleado " + nroPuesto);
        System.out.println(Cola.getTam());

        getProxTurno();

        while(proxTurno != null) {
            System.out.println("El próximo turno es: " + proxTurno);
            System.out.println("Presione Q para llamarlo.");

            String llamar = s.next();
            if(llamar == "Q"){
                llamar();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Me arroja el siguiente error, como si la lista estuviera vacía.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:266)
at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)
at turnero.Cola.getElem(Cola.java:22)
at turnero.TerminalEmpleado.getProxTurno(TerminalEmpleado.java:12)
at turnero.TerminalEmpleado.main(TerminalEmpleado.java:41)
```

Cabe destacar que primero ejecuto la clase TerminalCliente para ir añadiendo turnos (la cual depuré y comprobé que los agregue a la Cola, sí lo hace) y luego ejecuto la clase TerminalEmpleados.

Agradecería mucho su ayuda ya que no logro comprender qué es lo que está sucediendo. Mil gracias.

Comment: ¿Y cómo haces para ejecutar `TerminalEmpleado` después de `TerminalCliente`? Por lo que observo esas clases no se relacionan y pienso que no pueden estar en el mismo proceso. Y si no están en el mismo proceso lo que `TerminalCliente` agregue a `Cola` no será visible por `TerminalEmpleado`

Comment: Nunca vas a ejecutar al final TerminalEmpleado  ya que esta es la que tiene el mètodo : main(String[] args) imagino es tu clase principal-

Comment: En getProxTurno() tienes un for  dónde inicializas i=Cola .GetTam() y los haces hasta que i < 0. La primera a ver Cola.GqtTam() devuelve 0 porque no tiene elementos, sin embargo entra la for y ejecutas Cola.GetElem(i) solicitas el elemento 0 que no existe Po no hay elementos aún
 Ese es tu error IndexOutofBoundException. Indice fuera de rango. En Java el primer elemento de un arreglo es el 0

Comment: @Lobos ¿Cómo sería eso de relacionarlas o que estén en un mismo proceso? Se supone que son dos terminales distintas que en teoría se ejecutarían desde dos equipos distintos. Yo lo que hago es ejecutar `TerminalCliente` y luego de ir agregando turnos, ejecutar en paralelo `Terminal Empleado`